# URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier returning nil for valid, containerId, entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud

I can't for the life of me get URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier to work for my iCloud container on iOS. I have:

Added the iCloud container to the app & provisioning profile on developer portal.

Set the iCloud entitlements including containers in Xcode.

Verified the team ID and entitlements in the signed app bundle:

```
turin:pkdiagram patrick$ codesign -d --ent :- build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Family\ Diagram.app

Executable=/Users/patrick/dev/pkdiagram/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Family Diagram.app/Family Diagram
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>8KJB799CU7.com.vedanamedia.familydiagram</string>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>iCloud.com.vedanamedia.familydiagram</string>
        <string>iCloud.com.vedanamedia.Family-Diagram</string>
        <string>iCloud.com.vedanamedia.PKDiagram</string>
        <string>iCloud.com.vedanamedia.familydiagrammac</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-services</key>
    <array>
        <string>CloudDocuments</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
    <string>8KJB799CU7</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>iCloud.com.vedanamedia.familydiagram</string>
        <string>iCloud.com.vedanamedia.Family-Diagram</string>
        <string>iCloud.com.vedanamedia.PKDiagram</string>
        <string>iCloud.com.vedanamedia.familydiagrammac</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
    <string>8KJB799CU7.com.vedanamedia.familydiagram</string>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Verified that iCloud is indeed enabled on the device:

```
if([NSFileManager defaultManager].ubiquityIdentityToken) {
```

Queried the doc path using .:

```
    NSString *teamID = @"8KJB799CU7"; // replace with your real Team ID
    NSString *bundleID = @"iCloud.com.vedanamedia.familydiagram";
    NSString *containerID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", teamID, bundleID];
    NSURL *_iCloudRoot = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:containerID];
```

Nothing seems to work, _iCloudRoot is always nil. Is there anything else I can check? I've been on this for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the documentation states pass TEAMID.CONTAINER as URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier to specify a container I had success just passing the the bundle identifier of the container.